# How to Implement composite primary key with Hibernate Annonations

Tags: hibernate, annotations

I would like to know how to create a Composite Combination through Hibernate annotation method.

I have 3 tables Employee, Department & Employee-Department-Juntion

Since I want to make Employee and Department as individual table, i created a Junction Table in order maintain the Many-to-Many relationship.

I would like to know how to Create Composite Primary Key for the Department Table
For the column Center_Code & Depart_Code through Hibernate Annotations.

Could you please somebody help me how to solve this issue.

Below Here I also attached the Table Relation Ship and the Java POJO Class.

**Table Relationship**

[image: Table Relationship]

**JAVA POJO CLASS**

```
package com.hibernate;

import java.util.Objects;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;

/**
 *
 * @author SPAR
 */
@Entity
public class Department {

    @Id
    private String cost_Center_Code;
    private String dep_Code;
    private String department;
    private String sub_Department;
    private String division;

    public String getDepartment() {
        return department;
    }

    public void setDepartment(String department) {
        this.department = department;
    }

    public String getDep_Code() {
        return dep_Code;
    }

    public void setDep_Code(String dep_Code) {
        this.dep_Code = dep_Code;
    }

    public String getCost_Center_Code() {
        return cost_Center_Code;
    }

    public void setCost_Center_Code(String cost_Center_Code) {
        this.cost_Center_Code = cost_Center_Code;
    }

    public String getDivision() {
        return division;
    }

    public void setDivision(String division) {
        this.division = division;
    }

    public String getSub_Department() {
        return sub_Department;
    }

    public void setSub_Department(String sub_Department) {
        this.sub_Department = sub_Department;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Department{" + "cost_Center_Code=" + cost_Center_Code + ", dep_Code=" + dep_Code + ", department=" + department + ", sub_Department=" + sub_Department + ", division=" + division + '}';
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 7;
        hash = 79 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.cost_Center_Code);
        hash = 79 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.dep_Code);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }
        final Department other = (Department) obj;
        if (!Objects.equals(this.cost_Center_Code, other.cost_Center_Code)) {
            return false;
        }
        if (!Objects.equals(this.dep_Code, other.dep_Code)) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@Entity
public class Department {

    @EmbeddedId
    private DepartmentId departmentId

    private String department;
    private String sub_Department;
    private String division;
}

@Embeddable
public class DepartmentId {
    @Column(name = "")
    private String cost_Center_Code;

    @Column(name = "")
    private String dep_Code;

    //getter, setter methods
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think,what you are looking for is `EmbeddedId`,You can do something like below.

1. First take out these column from your `Department` class,and create a new class like below.

   ```
       @Embeddable    
       class CenterDeptId{

          @Column(name = "center_code")
          private String cost_Center_Code;

          @Column(name = "dep_code")
          private String dep_Code;

          // getter && setter 

      }
   ```
2. Use the above class in your Department class

   ```
   @Entity    
   public class Department {

       @EmbeddedId
       private CenterDeptId centerDeptId;
       private String department;
       private String sub_Department;
       private String division;

     //getter && setter

   }
   ```